# Is it necessary to broadcast an object member in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

Say I have an object and I need to make some operations towards the member of this object: `arr`.

```
object A {
  val arr = (0 to 1000000).toList
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //...init spark context
    val rdd: RDD[Int] = ...
    rdd.map(arr.contains(_)).saveAsTextFile...
  }
}
```

What is the difference between broadcasted `arr` and not broadcasted? 
i.e.

```
val arrBr = sc.broadcast(arr)
rdd.map(arrBr.value.contains(_))
```

and

```
rdd.map(arr.contains(_))
```

In my opinion, the object `A` is a singleton object, so it will be transferred through the nodes in Spark.

Is it necessary to use broadcast in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case

```
rdd.map(arr.contains(_))
```

`arr` is serialized shipped for each task

while in

```
val arrBr = sc.broadcast(arr)
rdd.map(arrBr.value.contains(_))
```

this is only done once per executor.

Therefore you should use broadcast when dealing with large datastructures.

Comment: Can I make `arrBr.value` a method?

Answer (score 2):

Just two additional things to mention beside Raphael's answer which is correct. You must always consider the size of the variable that you broadcast this shouldn't be too large otherwise Spark will face difficulties to distribute it efficiently along the cluster. In your case is:

```
4B x 1000000 = 4000000B ~ 4GB
```

which exceeds already the default value 4MB and can be controlled by modifying the [value](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior) of `spark.broadcast.blockSize`.

Another factor to decide whether to use or not broadcast is when you have [joins](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html) and want to avoid shuffling. By broadcasting a dataframe the keys will be available immediately in the node and hence avoid retrieving data from different nodes(shuffling).